# Call non-static member of static property in static class with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

I have a static class which looks for an implementation of an abstract type and stores it as a static property
similar to the below:

```
public static class MyStaticClass
{
    private static MyAbstractType _MyAbstractImplementation;

    public static MyAbstractType MyAbstractImplementation
    {
        get => _MyAbstractImplementation ?? ( _MyAbstractImplementation = FindImplementation());
        private set => _MyAbstractImplementation = value;
    }
}
```

And I am trying to call a method of MyAbstractImplementation (which contains no static properties or methods) via reflection:

```
var myAssembly = Assembly.Load("MyStaticClassAssembly")

var myType = myAssembly.GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == "MyAbstractType");

var myImplementation = myType.GetProperties()
    .First(p=>p.ReflectedType?.Name == "MyAbstractImplementation")
    .GetValue(null);

var obj = myType.GetMethod("SomeMethod")?.Invoke(
                null,
                new object[] 
                {
                    // Some args
                });
```

The above code causes the following exception on getting the value of `MyAbstractImplementation`:

```
System.Reflection.TargetException: Non-static method requires a target.
```

Evidently, this is because I am passing null to `GetValue()`, so I try passing `myAssembly` rather than null and I get the following exception:

```
System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.
```

Out of desperation, I try passing `myType` and `myImplementation` but I still get the same exception.

What am I meant to be passing to `GetValue()`?

Comment: Could you also post the code of the type `MyAbstractType`

Comment: You are retrieving the type of `MyAbstractType` not from `MyStaticClass` so I can assume `MyStaticClass` also has an implementation of `MyAbstractImplementation` but is not static. May be you wanted to do `myAssembly.GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == "MyStaticClass");`?

Comment: While fixing a typo in the question, I found the bug. MyAbstractType and MyAbstractImplementation have very similar names in code and I had them mixed up. So I was looking for `SomeMethod` in `MyAbstractType`, not `MyAbstractImplementation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error you are getting `MyAbstractImplementation` is not a static property, so it needs an instance to be run on.  You are basically trying to write the following code:

```
new MyAbstractType().MyAbstractImplementation.SomeMethod();
```

Both the property and method access need the target to run against (the left side of '.'). So you need an instance of `myType`. Also the method will need the instance, which is the result of getting the property (`myImplementation`).

```
var myAssembly = Assembly.Load("MyStaticClassAssembly");

var myType = myAssembly.GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == "MyAbstractType");
var myTypeInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);  // Asuming has a default constructor 

var myImplementation = myType.GetProperties()
    .First(p => p.ReflectedType?.Name == "MyAbstractImplementation")
    .GetValue(myTypeInstance);

var obj = myType.GetMethod("SomeMethod")?.Invoke(
                myImplementation,
                new object[]
                {
                    // Some args
                });
```

From how you write the code `myImplementation` should also be of type `myType` (`myType.GetMethod("SomeMethod")`) if it isn't replace it with: `myImplementation.GetType().GetMethod("SomeMethod")`.

Comment: Thank you for your help and response, while reviewing my question after getting your answer, I found the bug. I was looking for `SomeMethod` within the type, not the implementation.